# How to cut off string with various lengths based on character?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I am having trouble getting the correct result with `CHARINDEX` . I have a column with the following dummy samples:

```
File Path

C/Desktop/Folder1/FileName1
C/Folder3/Filename2
C/Folder4/Folder5/Folder6/Filename3
```

And I would like it to return the following:

```
Filename1
Filename2
Filename3
```

Is it possible to cut off the string in such a way?

Comment: check this:http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/how-to-extract-filename-from-path-using-sql-functions.aspx

Comment: Please tag dbms product used, since some of them need product specific SQL do solve this.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that, its T-SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let assume your full paths are stored in table fileinfo in column FullFilePath

```
SELECT
 LTRIM(
  RTRIM(
   REVERSE(
    SUBSTRING(
     REVERSE(FullFilePath),
     0,
     CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(FullFilePath),0)
    )
   )
  )
 )
FROM Fileinfo
```

Comment: Please specify which dbms this is for. (No dbms tagged.)

Comment: obviously he has tagged sql for it, then it is for sql only

Comment: And SQL is ANSI SQL, which does not include LTRIM, RTRIM, REVERSE or CHARINDEX...

Answer (score 2):

Try `PATINDEX` (Transact-SQL)

```
SELECT RIGHT(FilePath, PATINDEX('%/%', REVERSE(FilePath))-1) FROM FileTable
```

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would use `RIGHT()` and `CHARINDEX()`:

```
select right(filepath, charindex('/', reverse(filepath)) - 1)
```